# restart zebra printer via powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, zebra-printer

I want to restart zebra printer via command line , not the printjob , i want restart the device remotely 
there is cmdlet in PowerShell for restart the servers,The Restart-Service cmdlet sends a stop message and then a start message to the Windows Service.

I want like this command for restart printer.

Comment: I dont know if that exist in cmdlet , cuz  I searched inside the cmdlet and I didn't find any thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset a ZPL printer by sending it the command ~JR. From the [ZPL II Programming Guide](https://www.servopack.de/support/zebra/ZPLII-Prog.pdf):

~JR
Power On Reset
Description  The ~JR command resets all of the printer’s internal software, performs a power-on self-test (POST), clears the buffer and DRAM, and resets communication parameters and default values. Issuing a ~JR command performs the same function as a manual power-on reset.

In Windows you can use one of the following commands, depending on the port used and other requirements: COPY, ECHO, PRINT, LPR. In powerShell, you may be able to use [out-printer](https://ss64.com/ps/out-printer.html).